# Proving that a function is differentiable given $|f(x + h) − f(x)| ≤ C|h|^{\alpha}$.

Tags: calculus

Let $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that
$$|f(x + h) − f(x)| ≤ C|h|^{\alpha}$$
for all $\;x,x + h\in(a,b)$, where C is a constant and $\alpha>1$. Show that f is differentiable on (a,b) and compute $f′(x)$ for $x \in (a,b).$

Could you give me a hint as how to proceed with this quesiton. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two words: Squeeze Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\;\alpha-1>0\;$ :

$$\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h\right|\le C|h|^{\alpha-1}\xrightarrow[h\to 0]{}0$$

Answer (score 0):

The function is also constant, since the derivative exists everywhere and is $0$ everywhere. Mean Value Theorem.